# A complex map issue in Java for sequence retrieval

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, sequence

The real question is I have a sequence as B C D A E , now I am inserting it into map as shown in above code. Now my work is to retrieve the original sequence with same order in java. Couldn't answer in interview. So curious to know the solution.

Initial Sequence : B C D A E

```
Map map = new map();
map.put(C, D);
map.put(B, C);
map.put(A, E);
map.put(D, A);
```

Req seq: B C D A E

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Looks like an unclear work dump of some sort. Please fix this by asking a clear question, and by showing your own efforts with your question including your own attempt at a code solution.

Comment: It was my fault...please check the question now and give me a brief solution?

Comment: Use a linked hash map to maintain insertion order

Comment: So if your initial sequence is B C D A E, why and how did the pairs get inserted in such a weird order?

Comment: I think you just need to figure this one out.  Start with the first letter, B.  How can you figure out that the first letter is B by looking at the map?  What interesting property does B have that the other letters don't?

Comment: In my map i am having C D B C A E D A after map.put() statement..so how to proceed?

Comment: that is what interviewer asked me, if i know the first element B , then i could figure out all elements. But how to know that first element is B???

Comment: @ashdas i think we all have a problem because your question doesn't make sense, your initial sequence is the same as your req sed and your map seems incomplete.

Comment: @ashdas for one, that is 100% not the code they showed you. It's broken and incomplete.

Comment: @JordanGS this is the actual code. I am having the snippet with me as he shared his screen with me.

Comment: `Map map = new map();` is broken syntax, you can't even make that instantiate and you're telling me that it's actual code? More like you got homework that you don't know how to do.

Comment: @ashdas also, you have a map of 4 elements, where is your 5th?

Comment: @ashdas how can your initial sequence and your req sequence be the same? How do you want to return E when your map doesn't contain an E as a key.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem with your question, you have a map which is a key value pairing. Which means that you can at most only return 4 elements, **not** 5.

assuming that you start at B and move alphabetically. You would iterate through keys `B, C, D, A` and would get a result of `C, D, A, E`.

To do this, you would create an iterator based of of your map and start adding items to a linked list after the key B is found, anything before that would not be entered. When you add the values to the linked list, you would also remove them from the iterator.

When the first loop finishes going through all 4 keys, it will have `C, D, A` in the linked list and the map will now have a size of 1 since you removed all the previous elements. At this point you're alphabetical order is guaranteed so you can just iterate through the list again but add to the linked list the remaining items. Which will yield a linked list containing `C, D, A, E`. Iterators are cheap. But there is **NO WAY** to get `B C D A E` as you asked simply because you ONLY have 4 elements. So if that really is the question you were given.

**Tell them it's not possible to get back 5 elements when given a map of 4.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("C", "D");
    map.put("B", "C");
    map.put("A", "E");
    map.put("D", "A");
    printMap(map);
}

public static void printMap(Map<String, String> mp) {
    LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();

    String keyStart = "B";
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        String key = (String) pair.getKey();
        if (!key.equals(keyStart)) {
            continue;
        }else{
            ll.add((String) pair.getValue());
            it.remove();
        }
    }
    Iterator it2 = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it2.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it2.next();
        String key = (String) pair.getKey();
        ll.add((String) pair.getValue());
        it2.remove();
    }
    System.out.println(ll);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation .. I got the point!! :)

Comment: Sorry, I believe this answer is totally wrong.  I can see an obvious way of getting a 5-element answer out of the map with 4 pairings.  The problem is that while I have a good guess as to what the interviewer was asking, the OP was so unclear about the problem that I did not want to answer based on my guess.  But since there's a clear answer if my guess is right, your assertion of "no way" in big bold letters is just wrong.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't know what your code does.  I have no idea why you'd use a `Map` iterator which returns things in basically a random order.  Your references to "alphabetical order" are confusing, since the OP's question had nothing to do with alphabetical order.  And since the problem seems to be to get a sequence out of a map, your line that defines `keyStart` by basically putting the answer in the program, instead of letting the program figure out the answer, is highly suspicious.

Comment: @ajb are you stupid? Do you just randomly complain and downvote without reading? OP stated in his comments he knows that the first key is B. The problem being that you have a key value pairing, E is missing from the keys and B is missing from the values, so NO there is not way to get that specific 5 element pairing. The fact that you think you can get 5 **distinct** values when you're only given 4 is highly suspicious. According to OP, if you know that B is the first key, then iterate through and get the required values. In which case it's just an alphabetical map starting from key B.

Comment: @ajb since OP knows that the first key is B, the key order would be B, C, D, A which equates to values of C, D, A, E. We're given enough information to assume that it's an alphabetical ordering of keys, starting at B and then looping back around and going up until B.

Comment: "He knows that the first key is B" -- of course, he knows the whole answer!!  The question is, how do you get the program to find the first key??  Also, what do you mean "you're only given 4 distinct values"?  There are five distinct values in the problem.  Also, you don't know what "alphabetical" means?  Alphabetical would mean A, B, C, D, E.  Also, iterating through a `HashMap` returns keys in a more or less unpredictable order.  Your code does not return keys in the required order.  Did you test it?  I just did, and it returns C, E, D, A in that order.

Comment: And I wrote two long comments explaining what was wrong with your answer, in detail, so why would you ask if I "randomly downvote without reading"?  That doesn't make a bit of sense.

Comment: @ajb the map iterator wouldn't return in a random order but rather in the order that they were placed into the map, if you run it you'll see. You can run it 1000 times and you'll get the same order every time, nothing random about it. The other thing is that while you say you have a way of getting a 5th element, how do you get a B when you don't have a B in values? You're thinking of discerning a 5th value which doesn't exist in our map. While you think you know what the interviewer was asking, this is what i think the interviewer was asking; Starting at B, how would you get the required seq

Comment: @JordanGS No, a map iterator does not return things in the order in which they're placed in the map.  The iterator does return things in the same order every time, but the order depends on the hash function and is meaningless.  To your question "How do you get a B when you don't have a B in values"?  You look in the keys, and find the key that isn't in the values.  That's how you find the key with no predecessor in the original sequence.  Anyway, at this point since you're convinced you know a lot more than you actually know, I see no more value in discussing this.

Comment: @ajb you're talking about value extrapolation, there's absolutely no need to go that far in this case. This is a very simple question and the answer entirely depends on your interpretation of OP's question. Either one of us could be wrong and there is nothing to indicate it's me. So yeah :/